# Is there a flaw in the ease of access to One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

One Piece is the ultimate treasure, located in the hardest spot to get to in the world, or is it? Recently, the Straw Hats left Dressrosa and arrived at Zou. Both places are inhabited with some sort of intelligent being (Zou's people may not be humans). If this continues, or even if it doesn't, wouldn't it be really easy for these people to check Raftel for One Piece?

I understand this makes for a better story, but isn't that a serious flaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the One Piece Wikia article on [Raftel](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Raftel), it says that:

> Gol D. Roger and his crew are the only known people to have reached the island. Roger offered Whitebeard the information on how to get to Raftel, but Whitebeard declined because of his own dreams of achieving a "family" of crew members instead of reaching One Piece. This also indicates that getting to the island is not as simple as sailing to the end of the Grand Line.

It has also become much harder because it seems that trying to get to Raftel has resulted in a stalemate between the Yonkou. If one tries to go there, the others will stop him and together could even decimate the Navy, let alone a pirate crew which tries to reach Raftel without defeating them. We saw what Whitebeard and Shanks did during the War of Marineford, and that's only two of them.

Comment: I didn't think about the yonkou stalemate, however your statement about Whitebeard and shanks is wrong - Whitebeard and 37 other crews fought the marines, shanks only came to end the fight.

Comment: I know. I'm referring to their strength. Whitebeard's crew was strong enough to take on the Marines, whereas Shanks was intimidating enough to end the war.

Comment: Btw, where did you get that "37 other crews" part from? I only remember Whitebeard's Crew, Luffy and his allies (Jinbei, Ivankov and all) fighting in the war..

Comment: @AshishGupta He is talking about the other pirate crews from the New World that backed Whitebeard during the war.

Comment: @Peter Oh yeah, my bad. Just checked the One Piece wiki again and saw that he was allied with 43 pirate crews. Before I posted that comment, I had checked the wiki and failed to find that part :|